# Mod Perl in ubuntu

Tags: perl, ubuntu, apache2, mod-perl2

I am trying to configure apache2 running on ubunutu 12.04 to run perl script. But the script is not running when i submit the get request from the client. 
Below is the default config i have made (after reading in internet):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /home/Suresh/myFiles
 <Directory /home/Suresh/myFiles>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews +ExecCGI
        AddHandler cgi-script .pl
        AllowOverride ALL
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
        ExpiresActive On
        ExpiresDefault "access plus 6 hours"
      <FilesMatch "\.(nff)">
            Header set Cache-control "max-age=0, no-cache, proxy-revalidate"
            Header set Content-Type "application/octet-stream"
            Header set Pragma "no-cache"
            Header unset Vary
            Header set Connection "Keep-Alive"
      </FilesMatch>
   </Directory>
```

I have a perl script saved in the /home/Suresh/myFiles with chmod 777 permissions. 
Below is the perl code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use CGI;
#require LWP::UserAgent;
my $q = new CGI;
my @rawCookies = split /~/, $ENV{'HTTP_COOKIE'};
my $extfile = '/home/suresh/Cookies.txt';
open(FH, ">>$extfile") or die "Cannot open file";
print FH "STB Cookies: ", $ENV{'HTTP_COOKIE'}, "\n";   
close FH;
```

The perl works perfectly fine when run with perl command.

The script is not getting executed in default config file. 
Can anyone suggest me what else needs to be done ?

Comment: What's in your error log?

Comment: The error log doesn't at any errors. The requested file has been served but didn't executed the perl script.

Comment: You are not using mod_perl here. This is just normal CGI.

Comment: Can you please suggest how I can use mod_perl?

Answer (score 0):

You should use this conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>  
  Alias /perl/ /home/Suresh/myFiles
  <Location /perl/>
      SetHandler perl-script
      PerlResponseHandler ModPerl::Registry
      PerlOptions +ParseHeaders
      Options +ExecCGI
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all 
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Then you must make your script executable `% chmod a+rx /home/Suresh/myFiles/script.pl`

Make restart apacher server and go to `http://localhost/perl/script.pl`

That's all.

P.S. More info you may find there http://perl.apache.org/sitemap.html